# Compare updated_at in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
time_shift = DateTime.now - 75000
@user.items.where(:updated_at < time_shift) { |item|
```

I get error

> comparison of Symbol with DateTime
>   failed

Why and how to fix it?

In model:

```
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
@user.items.where("updated_at < ?", time_shift)
```

Comment: +1, This will work, let rails do date comparison rather doing it manually. this is the best way to dealing with date comparison for active record query.

Answer (score 0):

**John's** answer doesn't seems to work with PostgreSQL. If you are using PostgreSQL use:

```
@user.items.where('"users"."updated_at" < ?', time_shift)
```